Multiple Multivariate Time series forecasting with LSTM along with some categorical features
Currently I am working on a timeseries data which looks like this
click to see data
The data consists of 5 companies, 15 products (each company has 3-5 products) and 6 different regions
Goal To build a single generalized model for forecasting
Question 1 Does making a single model proper way.
I choose LSTM for modeling,
Question 2 Is LSTM a right choice if not, which approach is idea for this kind of data?
for training the LSTM I am taking past 120 days data and making prediction for next 30 days, for the input I am using last 120 days data except Sales, followed this article
and target has next 30 days Sales
My approach
DATA PREPROCESSING ( no need to see all the class, just see preprocess function u get an idea of wt its doing and also see into create sequences function for how input and output data is made)
class DataPreprocess:
    def __init__(self, data_path) -> None:
        self.df= pd.read_csv(data_path, index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
        
    def preprocess(self, check_model):
        self.feature_extraction()
        self.encode_features()
        self.split_data()
        self.scale_features()
        train_loader, test_loader= self.get_dataloader(check_model)

        return train_loader, test_loader

    def get_sin(self, X, period):
        return np.sin(2*np.pi * (X/period))

    def get_cos(self, X, period):
        return np.cos(2*np.pi * (X/period))

    def feature_extraction(self):
        self.df['DayOfYear']= self.df.index.dayofyear
        self.df['DayOfWeek']= self.df.index.dayofweek
        self.df['Seconds']= self.df.index.map(pd.Timestamp.timestamp)

        self.df['Week Sin']= self.df['DayOfYear'].apply(lambda x: self.get_sin(x, 7))
        self.df['Week Cos']= self.df['DayOfYear'].apply(lambda x: self.get_cos(x, 7))

        self.df['Month Sin']= self.df['DayOfYear'].apply(lambda x: self.get_sin(x, 30))
        self.df['Month Cos']= self.df['DayOfYear'].apply(lambda x: self.get_cos(x, 30))

        self.df['Year Sin']= self.df['DayOfYear'].apply(lambda x: self.get_sin(x, 365))
        self.df['Year Cos']= self.df['DayOfYear'].apply(lambda x: self.get_cos(x, 365))
        
        self.df.drop(['DayOfYear'], axis=1, inplace= True)

    def encode_features(self):
        categorical_features = ['Company', 'Product', 'Region']
        numerical_features = self.df.columns

        encoders= {}

        for col in categorical_features:
            le= LabelEncoder()
            self.df[col]= le.fit_transform(self.df[col])
            encoders[col]= le
    
        with open('artifacts/LSTM/encoders.pkl', 'wb') as file:
            pickle.dump(encoders, file)

    def split_data(self):
        self.train_df= self.df.groupby(['Product', 'Region']).head(-200)
        self.test_df= self.df.groupby(['Product', 'Region']).tail(200)

    def scale_features(self):
        standard_scaler_cols= ['Company', 'Product', 'Region', 'DayOfWeek', 'Seconds',
       'Week Sin', 'Week Cos', 'Month Sin', 'Month Cos', 'Year Sin',
       'Year Cos']
        
        standard_scaler= StandardScaler()
        min_max_scaler= MinMaxScaler()

        self.train_df[standard_scaler_cols]= standard_scaler.fit_transform(self.train_df[standard_scaler_cols])
        self.test_df[standard_scaler_cols]= standard_scaler.transform(self.test_df[standard_scaler_cols])

        self.train_df[['Sales']]= min_max_scaler.fit_transform(self.train_df[['Sales']])
        self.test_df[['Sales']]= min_max_scaler.fit_transform(self.test_df[['Sales']])

        with open('artifacts/LSTM/standard_scaler.pkl', 'wb') as file:
            pickle.dump(standard_scaler, file)

        with open('artifacts/LSTM/min_max_scaler.pkl', 'wb') as file:
            pickle.dump(min_max_scaler, file)

    def create_sequences(self, df, past_window_size= 120, forecast_window_size= 30):

        X= []
        y= []

        logger.info(f'creating sequences with past window : {past_window_size}, forecast_window : {forecast_window_size}')
        
        for prod, reg in df[['Product', 'Region']].drop_duplicates().values:
            df_to_np= df[(df['Product']==prod) & (df['Region']==reg)].to_numpy()
            
            for i in range(len(df_to_np)- past_window_size- forecast_window_size):
                # row= [r for r in df_to_np[i:i+past_window_size]]
                row= df_to_np[i:i+past_window_size, 1:]
                X.append(row)
                # label= [r[0] for r in df_to_np[i+past_window_size: i+past_window_size+forecast_window_size]]
                label= df_to_np[i+past_window_size:i+past_window_size+forecast_window_size, 0]
                y.append(label)
                
        return np.array(X, dtype=float), np.array(y, dtype= float)

    
    def get_dataloader(self, check_model):
        X_train, y_train= self.create_sequences(self.train_df)
        X_test, y_test= self.create_sequences(self.test_df)

        X_train, y_train= torch.from_numpy(X_train).float(), torch.from_numpy(y_train).float()
        X_test, y_test= torch.from_numpy(X_test).float(), torch.from_numpy(y_test).float()

        if check_model:
            train_dataset= TensorDataset(X_train[:5000], y_train[:5000])
            test_dataset= TensorDataset(X_test[:1000], y_test[:1000])
        else:
            train_dataset= TensorDataset(X_train, y_train)
            test_dataset= TensorDataset(X_test, y_test)

        train_loader= DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=32, drop_last=True, num_workers=4, pin_memory=True) 
        test_loader= DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=32, drop_last=True, num_workers=4, pin_memory=True)

        return train_loader, test_loader

in create_sequences function I am generating the last 120 X and next 30 y
MODEL I AM USING
from torch import nn
import torch

class LSTM_Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size, num_layers, dropout_prob=0.3):
        super(LSTM_Model, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, batch_first=True, num_layers=num_layers, dropout=dropout_prob)

        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size * 2) 
        self.batch_norm1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_size * 2) 
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()  
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout_prob) 
        
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size * 2, output_size) 
        # self.batch_norm2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_size)  
        # self.linear3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, X):
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, X.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(X.device)
        c0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, X.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(X.device)
        
        output, (hidden, cell) = self.lstm(X, (h0, c0))

        out = self.linear1(hidden[-1, :, :])
        out = self.batch_norm1(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.dropout(out)

        out = self.linear2(out)
        # out = self.batch_norm2(out)
        # out = self.relu(out)
        # out = self.dropout(out)

        # # Output layer
        # out = self.linear3(out)

        return out

MODEL TRAINING

from tqdm import tqdm
from pathlib import Path
import sys
import torch
from torch import nn
from datetime import datetime
import os

parent_dir= Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent
sys.path.append(str(parent_dir))

from data_preprocess import DataPreprocess
from LSTM_model import LSTM_Model
from src.utils.logger import get_logger

logger= get_logger()

class LSTM:
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size, num_layers, drop_out= 0.3) -> None:
        self.model = LSTM_Model(input_size, hidden_size, output_size, num_layers, drop_out)

    def train(self, epochs, train_loader, test_loader, load_model, save_every=10, model_path= None):
        self.loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()
        self.model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path)) if load_model else None
        self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr=0.001, weight_decay=1e-5)

        now = datetime.now()
        formatted_time = now.strftime("%d-%m-%y_%H-%M")
        formatted_time
        os.makedirs(f'artifacts/LSTM/{formatted_time}')

        for epoch in range(epochs):
            self.model.train()
            train_loss = 0.0
            for X, y in tqdm(train_loader):
                self.optimizer.zero_grad() 
                outputs = self.model(X)
                loss = self.loss_fn(outputs, y)
                train_loss += loss.item()
                loss.backward()
                torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(self.model.parameters(), max_norm=1.0)
                self.optimizer.step() 
               
            avg_train_loss = train_loss / len(train_loader)

            print(f'Epoch {epoch+1} --- train loss {avg_train_loss}')

            self.model.eval()
            test_loss = 0.0
            with torch.no_grad():
                for X, y in tqdm(test_loader):
                    outputs = self.model(X) 
                    loss = self.loss_fn(outputs, y) 
                    test_loss += loss.item()

            avg_test_loss = test_loss / len(test_loader)

            self.model.train()

            print(f'Epoch {epoch+1} --- test loss {avg_test_loss}\n')

            with open(f'artifacts/LSTM/{formatted_time}/metrics.txt', 'a') as file: 
                file.write(f"Epoch {epoch+1} : \n\ttrain loss {avg_train_loss} \n\ttest loss {avg_test_loss}\n\n")

            if epoch % save_every ==0 :
                torch.save(self.model.state_dict(), f'artifacts/LSTM/{formatted_time}/lstm_epoch_{epoch+1}.pth')

    def predict(self, X, model_path):
        '''
        X: past 120 days records
        '''
        self.model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path))
        self.model.eval()
        preds= self.model(X).detach().numpy().flatten()
        
        return preds


if __name__=='__main__':
    data_preprocess= DataPreprocess(data_path= 'data/inputs/Corrected_and_Balanced_Time_Series_Data.csv')
    logger.info('Started Data Preprocessing')
    train_loader, test_loader= data_preprocess.preprocess(check_model= False)  
    logger.info('Done Data Preprocessing')
    lstm= LSTM(1, 256, 30, 2, 0.5)
    lstm.train(epochs=10, train_loader=train_loader, test_loader=test_loader, load_model=False, save_every=1)

results
Epoch 1 :
train loss 0.004617819177448817
test loss 0.006365457516637564

Epoch 2 :
train loss 0.0013970815729702321
test loss 0.010996414257221789

Epoch 3 :
train loss 0.0023961294302583384
test loss 0.012776140605897776

please suggest me where I am going, or suggest a better way.

I heard about a really interesting alternative to using LSTMs or RNNs for time series data recently. You convert each time series into an image using a technique called Gramian Angular Fields, then you just train them on a convolutional neural network. I've heard that they're easier to train than LSTMs, maybe you could try that. Markov Transition Fields are also used to convert time series into images to train on a convolutional net.
I've never tried it, but I've heard of someone trying LSTMs and RNNs and they didn't work, but they tried Gramian Angular Fields and Markov Transition Fields as input to a convolutional neural network and it worked.

Thanks buddy for the suggestion,  definitely I will try that out if this doesnt work. :)

Cool, just a note: I noticed that I've only seen this used for time series classification and not time series forecasting, but it might work for forecasting.
